# Gather scatter like operation using WCF and C# (F#)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, f#

What is the best way to implement Gather-Scatter like operation using WCF and C# (or F#)?

1. Lets say that I have 20 nodes (computers) connected by WCF.
2. Each node computes a `time duration` value and sends this value to the `main node`.
3. The `main node` takes the minimum value of all the incomming ones and sends this information back to all the nodes.

EDIT:

The resulting code:

```
open System.ServiceModel
open System.ServiceModel.Channels

let numberOfClients = 10

type IMyContractCallback =
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract GetDuration: duration: float -> unit

[<ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof<IMyContractCallback>)>]
type IMyContract =
    [<OperationContract>]
    abstract SendDuration: duration: float -> unit

[<ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant)>]
type MyService () =

  let mutable totDuration = 1.
  let callbacks = System.Collections.Generic.Stack ()

  interface IMyContract with
    member o.SendDuration (duration) =
        totDuration <- min totDuration duration
        callbacks.Push (OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyContractCallback>())
        printfn "N = %d" callbacks.Count
        if callbacks.Count = numberOfClients then
          for c in callbacks do c.GetDuration (totDuration)

  interface IMyContractCallback with
    member o.GetDuration (duration) = printfn "Minimum duration = %g" duration

let address = "net.pipe://localhost/aaa"

let service = MyService ()
let pipe = new NetNamedPipeBinding()

let host = new ServiceHost(service)
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof<IMyContract>, pipe, address) |> ignore
host.Open()

for i in 0 .. numberOfClients - 1 do
  let client1 = System.Threading.Thread (fun () ->
    let fact = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyContract>(new InstanceContext(service), pipe, address)
    let ch = fact.CreateChannel()
    ch.SendDuration (0.4 + float i) )
  client1.Start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with WCF.
Implement a callback on the client nodes that the server will fire after computing the minimum value.

See [WCF Callbacks; a beginners guide](http://idunno.org/archive/2008/05/29/wcf-callbacks-a-beginners-guide.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. This hint helped a lot. Now it works like a charm (see my first post).